# Allocating memory to a 2D array in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Why can't I allocate each index of a 2D array individually.
Is there any correct and proper way to allocate memory if you want to use a dynamically allocated array in C?
I am getting a segmentation error for this code
here is my code:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    char ***sheet;
    int columns;
    int rows;
 } SPREADSHEET;  // to access data sheet[COL][ROW]



 SPREADSHEET *createSpreadSheet(int columns, int rows) {
    if (columns <= 0 || rows <= 0){  // Disallow 0 or negative rows/columns
        return NULL;
    }
    SPREADSHEET *sp = malloc(sizeof(SPREADSHEET));
    sp->columns = columns;
    sp->rows = rows;



    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
            printf("i: %i, j: %i\n", i, j);
            sp->sheet[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(char(*))+2);
        }
    }
    return sp;
 }
```

Comment: Three stars, two mallocs, off by one. Usually that cursory observation indicates problems. Each star means one level of pointing. For each level you need to be able to explain how the memory it is pointing to gets allocated. Please do so in your question to improve clarity.

Comment: You never make `sheet` point anywhere.

Comment: And `sizeof(char(*))` is the size of a *pointer* to `char`. That is equal to `4` or `8` (depending on 32 or 64 bit system). If you want space for three characters (***including*** the null-terminator) then that's just `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int columns;
  int rows;
  char sheet[];
} SPREADSHEET;

SPREADSHEET *sp = malloc( sizeof(SPREADSHEET) + sizeof(char[columns][rows]) );
sp->columns = columns;
sp->rows = rows;

for(size_t i=0; i<columns; i++)
{
  for(size_t j=0; j<rows; j++)
  {
    sp->sheet[i*rows + j] = something;
  }
}

...
free(sp);
```

Where `sheet` is a so-called *flexible array member*. It has to be declared last in the struct, and it's guaranteed to behave deterministically when you allocate trailing memory after the struct itself. The variable in itself does not add to the size of the struct.

Unfortunately C only allows single row flexible array members, so you have to use a "mangled 2D array" if you wish to use it as in your case. It means we calculate the array index manually in run-time, in order to access the array items.

Alternatively, you can access the items through a temporary array pointer, which is also well-defined:

```
char (*arr)[rows] = (void*) sp->sheet;
for(size_t i=0; i<columns; i++)
{
  for(size_t j=0; j<rows; j++)
  {
    arr[i][j] = something;
  }
}
```